# Is this a good idea to separate Grounds via ferrite beads?

Tags: noise, ferrite

is this a good idea to separate the GND of different parts of a circuit trough Ferrite Beads?
I have different parts in my board:
1- Microcontroller unit
2- Digital Inputs
3- Digital Outputs
4- Analog Inputs
5- Analog Outputs
6- PWM Outputs
7- RS485 Outputs
8- Ethernet connection

the general idea is like this, using a 50ohm@100Mhz 1206 ferrite bead:
[image]

Comment: I consolidated my comments into an answer. I suggest you wait at least 24 hours to see if you get a better answer before accepting an answer officially. From a book-keeping perspective, it is nice if questions eventually either get answered or closed.

Comment: If this is being copied from and existing circuit it may be the result of prior testing where the system was improved with the addition of a ferrite bead.  One option would be to initially design in a zero ohm resistor (of the same physical size), then after initial testing if there is a noise issue a ferrite bead could be installed and the system retested, and if found to be helpful just the parts list needs to be revised, (with out redesigning the PCB layout).

Comment: What do you intend to solve? Do you expect problems?

Comment: @mkeith I created a ground plane in top and bottom layer (my design is a 2layer board). thank you for your suggestions

Comment: @Nedd thank you for your time. no it's not a copy from an existing board

Comment: @RemyHx I just wanted to the EMI noise created by different parts have minimum effect on the rest parts

Comment: @EricMatevosian ah ok. I would go for a 4 layer board, layer 2/3 GND with prepeg as small as possible. Like the JLCPCB 3313. Ground fill isn’t needed then and the extra cost is minimal.

Comment: If you have to ask the question, the answer is "no". If you have detailed electromagnetic understanding of your circuit, the answer could be "maybe, in just the right place".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually anything that increases impedance between grounds will have undesirable side effects. Also, sometimes ferrite beads lead to oscillation or ringing at low to moderate frequencies. I would suggest that you not do this.

By all means, keep analog inputs away from all signals which change rapidly (for example PWM outputs). But I would do this by placement and routing, not by putting ferrites between different "grounds."

Sometimes, if careful attention to return currents is given, it is possible to have, for example, two different ground planes on the same layer with a split between them (joined only in one place) But this only works when done very carefully by knowledgeable people. I don't think I have ever done a split GND plane. I think it would only be needed in applications which are very sensitive to noise such as sensitive radio receivers or analog inputs which must have very low noise.